# About accuracy of LSTM

Tags: python, lstm, metrics

I just built a price prediction model with LSTM and the RMSE was approximately 0.12. The price range is from 0 to 3. Does it mean the model is accurate? Are there any other ways to measure LSTM's accuracy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy in this sense  is fairly subjective. RMSE means that on average your LSTM is off by 0.12, which is a lot better than random guessing.

Usually accuracies are compared to a baseline accuracy of another (simple) algorithm, so that you can see whether the task is just very easy or your LSTM is very good.

There's definitely [other ways to measure accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142873/how-to-determine-the-accuracy-of-regression-which-measure-should-be-used), but you should really be considering whether being off by on average 0.12 is good for your task specifically or good in comparison to other regressions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you measure **MAE** instead of RMSE, as it is the L1 is a more "natural metric".

If you want to estimate how good is your model, you need to build **baselines**. You could check for example how does the error change it you predicted always the average, or if you predicted always the last available data point.

That said, once you compute that, you could calculate relative metrics, for example the MAE of your model divided by the MAE of one of those Benchmarks. This builds upon the idea of the **MASE** metric from Rob Hyndman. I recommend you to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

One 'easy' way to test whether this performance is good, is to calculate the RMSE of a naive forecast. A naive forecast is forecasting the value from the previous step.
So if your series has the values [0, .2, .8, 2.2, 1.1], then the next predicted value would be '1.1'.

The RMSE from your LSTM should be smaller than the RMSE from your naive forecast, but even a smaller RMSE is no guarantee that your model is good.